# What is the life of the object instantiated in a function and a method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

An object instantiated in method of class like below, when would the object of A destroyed.

````
```
#module1.py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ""
        self.b = ""
    def method1(self):            
        pass
````

````
 ```
 #module2.py

 #scenario 1
 from module1 import A
 def func1():
     var1 = A()
     va2 = var1.a
 #Scenario 2
 class B:
    def method1(self):
       var1 = A()
       self.var2 = var1.a
````

When will the object of A be garbage collected. In case of scenario2 will the object be still alive or are there any chance of orphaned. Python version 3.9

Comment: If you still have a reference to the object, then the object won't be garbage collected. The *variable* is not the *object*. The variable is lost when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Note that while homework is allowed here in general, we want you to focus a question on _the specific part you don't understand_ that prevents you from answering it yourself. Explain what you _do_ understand is, what your reasoning is, and exactly _why and how_ that reasoning leaves you uncertain, instead of just asking us to solve what looks very much like a homework / classroom problem on your behalf.

Comment: @khelwood So the object of A is still there in Scenario2 ? If yes, will the object of A be garbage collected once method1 completes execution? Can you pls explain as you do for a dummy.

Comment: You don't keep any reference to the instance of `A` after your method ends, so at that point it's eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @khelwood , since I am assigning it to a self variable of class B the object is still alive till the class B object is garbage collected, is it like this?

Comment: In your code you set `self.var2` to `var1.a`, which is a string, not an instance of A.